# Using both hands to do the same thing (word request)

Tags: word-request

Are there any words to distinguish the activities of using both hands separately, like when typing on the computer or when drawing, in which case each hand does something different versus using both hands doing the same thing like when throwing a ball or pulling a rope ?

Comment: bimanual? Ambidextrous?

Comment: When pulling a rope often the two hands are doing different things for a lot of the time. Ambidextrous is probably wrong - it refers to a person who can use either hand equally well. A two-handed (bimanual) task is one that needs two hands, but often they do different things, like holding a bottle and turning the lid. I don't know the word you want.